# srcset attribute not showing the correct image from sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive

I created a HTML page with responsive images. I use srcset attribute with sizes for select different sizes of same image.

```
<img    src="{{ $img_array[2] }}"
    srcset="{{ $img_array[0] }} 100w,
    {{ $img_array[1] }} 160w,
    {{ $img_array[2] }} 350w,
    {{ $img_array[3] }} 550w,
    {{ $img_array[4] }} 750w,
    {{ $img_array[5] }} 1000w"

    sizes=" (max-width:374px) 334px,
    (max-width:479px) 439px,
    (max-width:575px) 535px,
    (max-width:767px) 58px,
    (max-width:991px) 58px,
    (max-width:1199px) 58px,
    58px"

    alt="test">
```

In 1199px width, 991px width and 767px width, The image is using in a carousel slide show thumbnail. When I testing this with iPad mini (DPR 2.0), I expect to load 160W image since DPR is 2. (58 x 2 = 116 so the closest image is 160W) But the browser load 550W image in every viewport size. How to fix this?